# How to resolve this error for SNMP v3 SOPHOS Firewall xg?

Tags: snmp, pysnmp, snmpv2c

This is the code I have used for receiving the SNMP trap messages from a firewall.

```
from pysnmp.carrier.asyncore.dgram import udp
from pysnmp.entity import engine, config
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413 import ntfrcv
from pysnmp.proto.api import v2c
from pysnmp import debug


def cbFun(snmpEngine, stateReference, contextEngineId, contextName,
          varBinds, cbCtx):
    execContext = snmpEngine.observer.getExecutionContext(
        'rfc3412.receiveMessage:request'
    )
    print('Notification from %s:%s' % execContext['transportAddress'])

    for var_bind in varBinds:
        print(f"Received OID: {var_bind[0]}, Value: {var_bind[1]}")


snmpEngine = engine.SnmpEngine())

# config.addV1System(snmpEngine, "user", "test")

# Setup transport endpoint
config.addSocketTransport(
    snmpEngine,
    udp.domainName,
    udp.UdpSocketTransport().openServerMode(("0.0.0.0", 162)),
)

config.addV3User(
    snmpEngine,
    "test",
    config.usmHMAC192SHA256AuthProtocol,
    "hasuhunjsnjnL@123",
    config.usmAesCfb128Protocol,
    "hasuhunjsnjnL@123",
    securityEngineId=v2c.OctetString(hexValue='80004f83983b30ea40'),
)
print("SNMP Trap; registering; Registered snmp v3 user %s", "test")

ntfrcv.NotificationReceiver(snmpEngine, cbFun)
debug.setLogger(debug.Debug('all'))

try:
    snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.jobStarted(1)
    snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.runDispatcher()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.closeDispatcher()

print("SNMP Receiver stopped.")
```

when i get the trap message from the firewall i am getting this error

```
2023-10-13 18:12:07,330 pysnmp: prepareDataElements: using sendPduHandle None for msgID 35729595
2023-10-13 18:12:07,330 pysnmp: StatusInformation: {'errorIndication': EngineIDMismatch('SNMP engine ID mismatch encountered')}
```

I have tried to query for Engine ID using the MIB browser then I get 80001f8880h7238781d65 as the Engine ID. When I run the code I am receiving this 80004f83983b30ea40 as the securityEngineID. Are they different and how to configure it in Sophos firewall xg?

Comment: Since you didn't share more information, we can only guess that this firewall uses different engine IDs when it responds to commands and sends out notifications.